Directions of puff pastry folds
I read a lot of tutorials about how to make folding for puff pastry, but no one told me clearly the directions of the folds.
My question is very simple: should the folds all be made in the same direction or should they be crossed between one rest and another?

They should alternate. The most common approach is the 3x3 “letter” fold, where you fold in thirds, turn 90 degrees, and fold in thirds again. If you only fold in one direction, the dough will become an impractically long and narrow rectangle.

Oh thank you! It's counter-intuitive anyway because I thought that to puff the layers had to be aligned!

@Mark The layers are aligned the way that a pile of sheets of paper are all parallel to one another, and that remains true if you fold the whole pile in half. The specific location of the folds is minor relative to the area where you have thin sheets of pastry separated by butter.
